# White Site after Ubuntu and PHP Update

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

i have a Problem. My Website is only a White Clean Site. With no Error, like nothing there.

Running Ubuntu 16.04, NGINX and PHP5.6-fpm

`/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock` is exists.

The Site is running before with my NGINX Settings, here is PHP location

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Before (Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP5-fpm) it was `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5-fpm.sock;`

But i cannot install php5-fpm anymore, cause Ubuntu 16.04 doesnt support it.

If i take a look to `/var/log/nginx/error.log` there is nothing! No Logs from the Site

I dont know what i can do... i tried php7.0 but also same look...

Outputs:
fpm grep

```
root      2214  0.0  0.1  14236  1024 pts/0    S+   16:26   0:00 grep --color=auto fpm
root     31797  0.0  2.2 234016 22504 ?        Ss   13:15   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 31802  0.0  7.1 280008 72224 ?        S    13:15   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 31803  0.0  5.9 280888 60328 ?        S    13:15   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
```

nginx grep

```
root       319  0.0  0.2 125368  3040 ?        Ss   13:32   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   320  0.0  0.6 125368  6776 ?        S    13:32   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      2219  0.0  0.1  14236  1020 pts/0    S+   16:27   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

status nginx

```
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-09-21 13:32:45 CEST; 2h 55min ago
 Process: 308 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
 Process: 316 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 313 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 319 (nginx)
  CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
       ├─319 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
       └─320 nginx: worker process

Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal nginx[313]: nginx: [warn] server name "/var/www/*****.de/htdocs" has suspiciou
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal nginx[313]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "*****.de" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal nginx[313]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "*****.de" on 0.0.0.0:80,
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal nginx[316]: nginx: [warn] server name "/var/www/*****.de/htdocs" has suspiciou
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal nginx[316]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "*****.de" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal nginx[316]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "*****.de" on 0.0.0.0:80,
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argum
Sep 21 13:32:45 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: did you check if the nginx service is actually running? try running `systemctl status nginx` as root and you should see whether or not it's running and if there's any errors.

Comment: To check that the webserver works, use a plain HTML file. If it works, then a blank PHP page usually means that you have a fatal error and you haven't switched on error reporting. Note that if it is a syntax error you cannot switch on error reporting in the script, since the script won't execute.

Comment: Add outputs of these commands `ls -alh /var/run/php/`, `ps aux | grep fpm`, `ps aux | grep nginx`, `systemctl status nginx` to your question

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani i added some infos in question

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i tried that...HTML File Works. Than i renamed the HTML File to .php and not working... white Site Only HTML Code in this file

Comment: I fixed all warn and error pid in nginx status but now the sites loading long time and gett ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT